# xml file linebreak request

Tags: node.js, xml

I am new with xlm files and I hope the solution is easy. I have built a file with xml-writer in node.js.
How can I insert linebreak or indentation into the file ?
Thanks

```
 xw = new XMLWriter();
      xw.startDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
      xw.startElement("1st element");
      xw.writeAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
      xw.writeAttribute(
        "A",
        "B"
      );
      xw.startElement("Lot");
      xw.startElement("RAW");
      xw.writeAttribute("E", F);
      xw.endElement();
      xw.endDocument()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with it, but the constructor for XMLWriter appears to have an "indent" parameter. Try `new XmlWriter(true)`.